# Функциональность метакласса на всех наследников, исключая базовый класс

Tags: python

У меня в приложении есть класс для наследования остальных подклассов. Одна из его задач в том, что он передаёт генерацию класса своему метаклассу, чтобы кроме наследования не нужно было дополнительно прописывать `metaclass=SmthMeta`.

```py
class ClassesMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, clsname, bases, dct):
        dct['b'] = dct.get('a', 0) + 10
        return super(ClassesMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, clsname, bases, dct)


class Base(metaclass=ClassesMeta):
    a = 5


class Child(Base):
    a = 10


Base.b  # 15
Child.b  # 20
```

Но проблема в том, что в логике моего приложения класс `Base` должен иметь атрибут `a  = None`, но всегда имеет переопределённый атрибут у детей, а также класс `Base` никогда не используется кроме как для наследования.

Но код

```py
class Base(metaclass=ClassesMeta):
    a = None

class Child(Base):
    a = 10
```

ожидаемо выдаст ошибку во время инициализации `Base`:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    class Base(metaclass=ClassesMeta):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 3, in __new__
    dct['b'] = dct.get('a', 0) + 10
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Итого: мне нужно сделать применение метакласса не непосредственно к классу с `metaclass=ClassesMeta`, а ко всем, наследованным от него. Пока что моё решение в том, чтобы фильтровать имя класса:

```py
class ClassesMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, clsname, bases, dct):
        if clsname == 'Base':
            return type.__new__(mcs, clsname, bases, dct)

        dct['b'] = dct.get('a', 0) + 10
        return super(ClassesMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, clsname, bases, dct)
```

Но это выглядит как большой костыль. Есть ли способ убрать для `Base` генерацию атрибута `b` более правильным способом?

Comment: Вы же в курсе что создаете "переменные класса", а не члены класса?

Comment: @JK_Action если честно, я не особо знаю различие между двумя этими понятиями. В чём будет разница между `Base.a` и `Base.b` из самого первого примера?

Comment: Я не смогу хорошо объяснить ищите ключевая фраза "python переменная класса"

Comment: Не понял особых различий, нашёл инфу только про разницу переменных классов и их инстансов.

Comment: Интересный заголовок вопроса.

Comment: @strawdog копипаст и недосмотр (почему нет pvs для стака?)  :)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка у Вас в том что метод get для словаря вернет значение по умолчанию если ключа не существует, а он есть просто равен None.

```
class ClassesMeta(type):
    def __new__(mcs, clsname, bases, dct):
        val = dct.get('a', 0)
        if val is None:
            val = 0
        dct['b'] = val + 10
        return super(ClassesMeta, mcs).__new__(mcs, clsname, bases, dct)
```

Comment: Это я понимаю, и это ожидаемое поведение питона на такой код. Моя проблема не в ошибке с `None`, моя проблема в том, что я не хочу исполнять код генерации на конкретном классе `Base`. Код здесь - абстракция над более раельной проблемой (кастомные подклассы `Column` из `sqlachemy`).

Comment: Кстати, `if val is None: val = 0` лаконичнее и почти всегда с той же юзабельностью меняется на `val = val or 0`.

Comment: Ну таком случае, наверное только фильтрация, может переформулируйте вопрос. Вам функциональность мета класса нужна через наследника? Может использовать декоратор класса для Child?

Comment: `Вам функциональность метакласса нужна через наследника` - да, правильная формулировка моей мысли, сейчас изменю заголовок. А декоратор класса мне не нравится по той же причине, по которой я изначально хотел уйти от `metaclass=ClassesMeta` - оно засоряет код лишним контекстом.

Comment: Так может вам наборот унаследовать мета класс от базового?